# RSA Archer - How to find workflows in an Archer GRC implementation

Tags: archer, rsa-archer-grc

in an Archer implementation where workflows are implemented, I would like to know how to identify them and how to recognize an advanced workflow.
Thank you in advance for your kind help.

Giovanni

Answer (score 0):

If an application is using Advanced Workflow you’d just click on the Advanced Workflow tab.  It will either display the configured workflow or ask to enable it.

Most of these questions are covered in the administration guide or searching the online help.